# Wi-Fi works fine on phone but not on laptop

Tags: router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, asus-laptop

My Wi-Fi works fine on my phone without any issues, but if I try to connect the same Wi-Fi on my laptop it says "*No Internet Connection*". **And if I open HotSpot from my phone which is connected to the same Wi-Fi it works there.** but when I directly try to connect to the router Wi-Fi it doesn't work.

I tried connecting with other Wi-Fi too and it worked but it isn't working particularly in that router. When I opened router config page it says "*WAN port is unplugged*" but it's working fine on phone!  When I open router config page from phone it shows everything right?

**I have such wired problem! How to fix it?**

PS: *I entered **192.168.0.1** to access from phone but that did'nt work when I tried from PC* *And It Opened when I entered **192.168.1.1** which showed same config page but with error message* !

**I'm sure I'm connected to same WI-Fi**

**EDIT**: I figured out when it's connected to 192.168.0.1 it works fine (Auto). I've added a picture of my LAN, thought it would help somehow.
[image: My LAN]

Comment: So..... Wifi has issues. WAN/Router has issues. And somehow your router has two LAN IPs but one only works on PC and the other works on phone too but shows an error message?......... Weird indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure which os version you are using, however, theses are some solutions.

1. forget the network from your PC, restart pc and try reconnecting.
2. login router and temporary change the wifi name to any other name and try connecting
3. open run and type NCPA.CPL, right-click and select the wifi adapter->> select properties -->>double click internet protocol v4 and under dns; type 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, check validate settings and okay...
4. same settings, check your ip range and assign a static ip for the pc. lemme know if you need any further help

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your help but it didn't work. I did everything you suggested but still can't resolve the problem. I found a weird thing again (posted a screenshot of it) [here](https://imgur.com/a/ACqzkSS) . Help me please :)

Comment: in case you are using a wireless extender, check the config as well

Comment: right, just like i said, change the wifi name to example, "test" and change the password to 1234abcd and try connecting on your computer it should work... lemme know if it works, then you change it to another name and password, if possible not the exact name like before.....

Comment: as I mentioned in **Edit** before Wi-Fi seems to work when the IP is **192.168.0.1** I don't know why but it changes automatically somehow to **192.168.1.1** and stops working again. [ScreenShot](https://imgur.com/a/EmKAk2P)